# How do I regain neutrality with Stormcloaks and Imperials?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven’t taken any sides as far as I know, but the Stormcloaks started calling me "unblooded" and the Imperials won’t let me anywhere near their camps. I’ve never hit a member of either faction as far as I know. I do help either if they are in trouble with bandits or bears or such, but never when fighting each other - I just move away fearful I might be drawn into taking sides.

Is there a console command to set me back as neutral with both factions?

Comment: the camps are always hostile as far as I know

Comment: @3ventic: I've gone near camps of both sides and had relatively friendly interactions. I'm about level 15 now and have not chosen sides in any way in the quests yet, although I'm leaning towards Imperial.

Comment: Actually, the camps are usually friendly -- they're generally trying to recruit you to their side.

Comment: Are you a vampire?  If both sides are hostile to you, it sounds like something else is a problem.

Comment: No not a Vampire.  I only have the problem when trying to enter an Imperial camp, not Imperials in general (in city’s or on the road) and the Stormcloaks like me and call me unblooded which I think means I’m one of them but haven’t done anything yet

Comment: I think I may have done something or said something to tip the balance ever so slightly towards the Stormcloaks which is my problem.

Comment: @Agnot2006 Possible spoiler so sorry for this, but have you done the peace talks in high hrothgar?

Comment: Yes a long long time ago I used only the options I thought were doing the least harm to either faction at the time.

Comment: Does this mean there is no solution – no Console command?

Answer (score 1):

Imperials and Stormcloaks both have hidden crime faction ratings that track your crime against them.

In order to reset your crime rating with each enter the following commands into the console:

Imperials:

```
player.paycrimegold 0 0 00028848
```

Stormcloaks:

```
player.paycrimegold 0 0 00028849
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through the console command list on the wiki and it's not there. If there is one it would be something like set.factionrep  0 or force.factionrep  0.

It might be wise to see if get.factionrep .

And if none of these work factionreputation might work where factionrep might not.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. This all started after you did that one quest with the burned down house and ghosts, didn't it?
 Yeah, you need to drink blood at night to remain inconspicuous, or find a black soul gem.